# PyDriller - "Reference is not a tree"

Tags: git, checkout

I am trying to traverse through the commits of a repository.

I am using PyDriller to do so. I initialise the repository as a PyDriller Git repo. I then checkout the PyDriller Git repo at each commit. It works for multiple commits until I try to checkout a **merge** commit. I receive this error

```
    git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git checkout -f c9e7ca3de6d9e99cfcc1439a877465e566f452b1
  stderr: 'fatal: reference is not a tree: c9e7ca3de6d9e99cfcc1439a877465e566f452b1'
```

I can manually checkout this commit using the terminal so I am unsure why it does not work using my python code

The code works like this:

```
current_repo = Git(config.CURRENT_REPO)

for commit in Repository(repo_path).traverse_commits():
    ...
    ...
    current_repo.checkout(commit_hash)
```

Which is confusing because this works until we hit a merge commit?

Comment: If the command works from the command line itself, the problem must be introduced by the Python code in some way. My suspicion is that the Python code changes its own working directory at some point, so that you're no longer referring to the same Git repository, but without knowing what this Python code is, that's just a guess.

Comment: @torek I have added a summary of the code

Comment: Are you trying to checkout a submodule?

Comment: @JechChua I don't think so, I am just trying to checkout the repository at a certain commit and it seems to work up until i try to checkout at a merge commit

Comment: Is it a shallow clone? I can't seem to recreate your issue. I've tried traversing repos with merge commits both with remote repo as well as clone on my disk. They all finished traversing okay. Is there any other thing you set up that's different?

Comment: It could be your repo is corrupted

Comment: I set up the repo object from the path to the cloned repo and then traverse its commits like I've shown in the question. Ive had the same problem on my other machine too. This checkout in the code is the only time I use the current_repo object so unsure how it is not working.

Comment: @MartinLopez : do you have the possibility to share the repo ? can you also display the code you elided with `...` in your snippet ?

Comment: Could you do a 'git pull --all' before anything else in your python script ? If it still occurs, that definitely a problem with your refspec or right access.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was to do with the HEAD detaching during the for loop. A work around I found was to pull master at the very start before running the program. Thank you everyone for your help!